# Mongodb always include certain fields in .watch()

Tags: mongodb

I'm using mongodb's change stream watch() function to look for changes to documents in a collection.  I'm only interested if there are changes to a few specific fields but if there are changes, I want always want the `userID` field to be returned.

This watches for changes to the `blocked` or `priceOverrideFormatted` fields but when there are changes, I need the `userID` field returned as well so I can notify the use using websockets.

How do I check for changes to `blocked` or `priceOverrideFormatted` and have it return the `userID` field?

```
Price.watch([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {"updateDescription.updatedFields.blocked": {$exists: true}},
                {"updateDescription.updatedFields.priceOverrideFormatted": {$exists: true}}
            ],
            operationType: {$in: ["replace", "insert", "update"]}
        }
    }
]).on("change", change => {
    const {fullDocument} = change;
    if (io) {
        io.to(fullDocument.userID.toString()).emit("price", fullDocument);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my issue.  You need to add the `{fullDocument: "updateLookup"}` options

```
Price.watch([
    {
        $match: {
            $or: [
                {"updateDescription.updatedFields.blocked": {$exists: true}},
                {"updateDescription.updatedFields.priceOverrideFormatted": {$exists: true}}
            ],
            operationType: {$in: ["replace", "insert", "update"]}
        }
    }
],
{fullDocument: "updateLookup"}
).on("change", change => {
    const {fullDocument} = change;
    if (io) {
        io.to(fullDocument.userID.toString()).emit("price", fullDocument);
    }
});
```

Comment: You also have the option to add stages, and bring in $project. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#modify-change-stream-output

Comment: @Yahya can you explain in more detail how stages and $project could help?  I'm very interested in making this better.